# How to change progress bar in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, progress-bar

I have html code. And i need some javascript code for update value on every iteration

```
<progress id="progressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>


for (i = 0; i <= 100; i ++) {
    //update progress bar
}
```

I try to do something like this:

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
progressBar.value += i;
```

But this not work. It update progress bar when loop finish.

Comment: Are you using jquery UI or some framework with this ?

Comment: *It update progress bar when loop finish.* Not really, it's just too fast to distinguish each individual update. ;)

Comment: not realy, i try progressBar.max = 10000000 before the loop and still immediately fill progress bar

Comment: The reason it's not working is dealt with in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767722/how-to-show-css-loader-while-syncronous-javascript-is-running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like that for a dummy progressbar :

**Html**

```
<div id="progress">
    <span class="progress-text"></span>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#progress {
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#progress .progress-bar {
    background:blue;
    height:20px;
    width:0%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#progress .progress-text {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    right:0;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progression = 0,
    progress = setInterval(function() 
    {
        $('#progress .progress-text').text(progression + '%');
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css({'width':progression+'%'});
        if(progression == 100) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            alert('done');
        } else
            progression += 10;

    }, 1000);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/66RmV/)

You could use the [JQueryUI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) too !

Comment: Thanks @soyuka, very usefull!

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for several days, and finally put what I had learned into the following fairly simple solution, which puts a button and a progressbar on an HTML page.

When the button is clicked, javascript starts a count, and updates the progress bar as the count progresses.  The count is set to a default value of 4321 in the button definition, but you can change it to any value you choose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Progress Bar Demo</title>
<script>
var button;
var count;
var countmax;
var progressbar;
var timerID;

function start(max) {
    button = document.getElementById("button");
    count = 0;
    countmax = max;
    progressbar = document.getElementById("bar");
    progressbar.max = countmax;

    timerID = setInterval(function(){update()},10);
}//end function

function update() {
    button.innerHTML = "Counting to " + countmax;
    count = count + 100;
    progressbar.value = count;
    if (count >= countmax) {
        clearInterval(timerID);
        button.innerHTML = "Ready";
        progressbar.value = 0;
    }//end if
}//end function

</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    <button onclick="start(4321)" id="button" style="font-size:18px;">Ready</button><br>
    <br>
    <progress id="bar" value="0"></progress>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write an asynchronous loop using setTimeout like this:

```
var counter = 0;
(function asyncLoop() {

    $('#progressBar').val(counter++);
    if (counter <= 100) {
        setTimeout(asyncLoop, 50);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#progressBar").prop("value",i);
```

should set the property value to whatever i is in that loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: i });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but just in case someone needs it some time:

```
$("progress").val(i);
```

will change the progress value base on value `i`.

---

As an example, for uploading an image you can use the jquery-form library `<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>`. So, you can update your `progress` html tag in the `uploadProgress` function of this library as follow:

```
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    progressBar.val(percentComplete);
},
```

See the demo of jquery-form [here](http://malsup.github.io/demo/progress.html) and mix it with the above knowledge if you want to use `progress` tag and be a bit more clear in coding.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Beware the "must be enough" timeouts, they highly depend on each machine's speed.
I discovered that `$('progress#id').text(Math.random())` forces the UI to redraw.