# Load progress bar during loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, loading

I have a loop that processes data for a while, so I'd like to show a progress bar while the loop is processing. I've tried updating the progress bar within each loop iteration:

```js
let data = new Array(1000000); //large input data

let progress_bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
let progress_text = document.getElementById('progress_text');
let progress = 0;
let full = data.length;

for (let row of data) {
    progress_bar.style.width = (100 * progress / full) + '%';
    progress_text.innerHTML = Math.round(100 * progress / full) + '%';

    processData(row);

    progress += 1;
}

function processData(input) {
    //process the line of data
}
```

```css
#progress_track {
    height: 5px;
    width: 80vw;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    background: #888;
}
#progress_bar {
    background: #54f;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
}
#progress_text {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id='progress_track'>
            <div id='progress_bar'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='progress_text'>0%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it updates all at once at the end.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743428/javascript-progress-bar-not-updating-on-the-fly-but-all-at-once-once-process) it explains that JavaScript only updates the UI at the end of something so rapid, so I tried replacing

```
    progress_bar.style.width = (100 * progress / full) + '%';
    progress_text.innerHTML = Math.round(100 * progress / full) + '%';
```

with

```
    if ((progress % 1000000) == 0) {
        progress_bar.style.width = (100 * progress / full) + '%';
        progress_text.innerHTML = Math.round(100 * progress / full) + '%';
    }
```

but that yields the same result.

I also tried using setTimeouts and setIntervals, but my understanding of callbacks isn't that great, so I ended up accidentally accessing the data before it was processed.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774245/how-to-change-progress-bar-in-loop ?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long running loops in JS freezes the UI refresh, to show the progress of data, you may need to move the data processing logic to web worker. You can read about web worker on the following link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Took me a while to understand how web workers work, but once I was able to implement it, it worked great!

Comment: Glad to hear. It is a quite a useful feature.